# Unexpected result when trying to compose a curried lambda with another lambda

Tags: c++, c++11, lambda, indices

I am toying with C++11 lambdas and was trying to mimick some function from the [`functional` module](http://dlang.org/phobos/std_functional.html) of the D programming language. I was actually trying to implement [`curry`](http://dlang.org/phobos/std_functional.html#curry) and [`compose`](http://dlang.org/phobos/std_functional.html#compose). Here is the `main` that I am trying to get working:

```
int main()
{
    auto add = [](int a, int b)
    {
        return a + b;
    };
    auto add5 = curry(add, 5);

    auto composed = compose(add5, add);
    // Expected result: 25
    std::cout << composed(5, 15) << std::endl;
}
```

The problem is that I don't get the same result from g++ and clang++. I get:

- 35 with g++ 4.8.1
- [25 with g++ 4.8.2](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e625ceb162b339db)
- 25 with g++ 4.9
- 32787 with clang++ 3.5 (trunk used with Coliru)

g++ 4.8.2 and 4.9 give me the expected result. The results obtained from g++ 4.8.1 and clang 3.5 do not depend on the value passed to `curry`. I first thought that this may be a compiler bug, but it is more likely that I have an error in my code.

---

Here is my implementation of `curry`:

```
template<typename Function, typename First, std::size_t... Ind>
auto curry_impl(const Function& func, First&& first, indices<Ind...>)
    -> std::function<
        typename function_traits<Function>::result_type(
        typename function_traits<Function>::template argument_type<Ind>...)>
{
    return [&](typename function_traits<Function>::template argument_type<Ind>&&... args)
    {
        return func(
            std::forward<First>(first),
            std::forward<typename function_traits<Function>::template argument_type<Ind>>(args)...
        );
    };
}

template<typename Function, typename First,
         typename Indices=indices_range<1, function_traits<Function>::arity>>
auto curry(Function&& func, First first)
    -> decltype(curry_impl(std::forward<Function>(func), std::forward<First>(first), Indices()))
{
    using FirstArg = typename function_traits<Function>::template argument_type<0>;
    static_assert(std::is_convertible<First, FirstArg>::value,
                  "the value to be tied should be convertible to the type of the function's first parameter");
    return curry_impl(std::forward<Function>(func), std::forward<First>(first), Indices());
}
```

And here is my implementation of `compose` (note that I only wrote a binary `compose` while the D one is variadic):

```
template<typename First, typename Second, std::size_t... Ind>
auto compose_impl(const First& first, const Second& second, indices<Ind...>)
    -> std::function<
        typename function_traits<First>::result_type(
        typename function_traits<Second>::template argument_type<Ind>...)>
{
    return [&](typename function_traits<Second>::template argument_type<Ind>&&... args)
    {
        return first(second(
            std::forward<typename function_traits<Second>::template argument_type<Ind>>(args)...
        ));
    };
}

template<typename First, typename Second,
         typename Indices=make_indices<function_traits<Second>::arity>>
auto compose(First&& first, Second&& second)
    -> decltype(compose_impl(std::forward<First>(first), std::forward<Second>(second), Indices()))
{
    static_assert(function_traits<First>::arity == 1u,
                  "all the functions passed to compose, except the last one, must take exactly one parameter");

    using Ret = typename function_traits<Second>::result_type;
    using FirstArg = typename function_traits<First>::template argument_type<0>;
    static_assert(std::is_convertible<Ret, FirstArg>::value,
                  "incompatible return types in compose");

    return compose_impl(std::forward<First>(first), std::forward<Second>(second), Indices());
}
```

The class `function_trait` is used to get the arity, the return type and the type of the arguments of a lambda. This code heavily relies on the indices trick. Since I don't use C++14, I don't use [`std::index_sequence`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/integer_sequence) but an older implementation under the name `indices`. `indices_range<begin, end>` is an indices sequence corresponding to the range `[begin, end)`. You can find the implementation of these helper metafunctions (as well as `curry` and `compose`) [on the online version of the code](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e625ceb162b339db), but they are less meaningful in this problem.

---

Do I have a bug in the implementation of `curry` and/or `compose` or are the bad results (with g++ 4.8.1 and clang++ 3.5) due to compiler bugs?

---

**EDIT:** You may find the code above not quite readable. So, here are versions of `curry` and `compose` that are exactly the same, but use alias templates to reduce the boilerplate. I also removed the `static_assert`s; while they may be helpful information, that's just too much text for the question and they do not play a part in the problem at hand.

```
template<typename Function, typename First, std::size_t... Ind>
auto curry_impl(const Function& func, First&& first, indices<Ind...>)
    -> std::function<
        result_type<Function>(
        argument_type<Function, Ind>...)>
{
    return [&](argument_type<Function, Ind>&&... args)
    {
        return func(
            std::forward<First>(first),
            std::forward<argument_type<Function, Ind>>(args)...
        );
    };
}

template<typename Function, typename First,
         typename Indices=indices_range<1, function_traits<Function>::arity>>
auto curry(Function&& func, First first)
    -> decltype(curry_impl(std::forward<Function>(func), std::forward<First>(first), Indices()))
{
    return curry_impl(std::forward<Function>(func), std::forward<First>(first), Indices());
}

template<typename First, typename Second, std::size_t... Ind>
auto compose_impl(const First& first, const Second& second, indices<Ind...>)
    -> std::function<
        typename result_type<First>(
        typename argument_type<Second, Ind>...)>
{
    return [&](argument_type<Second, Ind>&&... args)
    {
        return first(second(
            std::forward<argument_type<Second, Ind>>(args)...
        ));
    };
}

template<typename First, typename Second,
         typename Indices=make_indices<function_traits<Second>::arity>>
auto compose(First&& first, Second&& second)
    -> decltype(compose_impl(std::forward<First>(first), std::forward<Second>(second), Indices()))
{
    return compose_impl(std::forward<First>(first), std::forward<Second>(second), Indices());
}
```

Comment: Can't you just solve it with `std::bind` for the currying part? Like `auto add5 = std::bind(add, _1, 5);`?

Comment: @JoachimPileborg It gives compiler errors. It seems that `function_traits` does not work for bind expressions; the reason would be that a bind expression has several overloads of `operator()`.

Comment: `return [&]` That looks highly suspicious. Such lambdas can be implemented by storing a pointer to EBP, instead of a reference to each captured entity. Are you sure you don't get lifetime issues with that?

Comment: In fact, if I replace the `[&]` with a `[=]` and the forwarding with moving, clang++ also prints 25.

Comment: @dyp Suspicious `[&]` is actually the reason I asked the question. If there is problem, it has to be with lifetime.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/q/21443023/420683

Comment: `auto curry(Function&& func, First first)` is taking `first` by value, and then tries to `std::forward` it.

Comment: I think you have to copy the arguments to `curry` *at least once*, so that the resulting `std::function` owns the arguments. Currently, there's a copy (because `curry` takes by value), but no copy ends up in the resulting `std::function` -- this means that `std::forward`ing the arguments makes no sense. In functional programming, there are no side effects (AFAIK), so move semantics itself should not be applied (otherwise, you can't apply that function object twice, e.g.).

Comment: @dyp You're right about the value forwarding. Seems like I forgot a `&&` when writing it.

Comment: :D Fix that and try again with g++

Comment: @If I only fix the `&&` (and not the `[&]` -> `[=]`), I get 25 with clang++ but not the expected result with g++ 4.8.2.

Comment: I think @dyp may have it. In MSVC12, I can only get the expected result if I do one of two things: 1) modify `curry` to take an r-value reference to `first`, or 2) modify the lambda in `curry_impl` to capture `first` by-value instead of by-reference.

Comment: @dyp Ok, if I fix the `&&` and then take `first` by value in the capture and `move` it, it seems to work with g++ 4.8.2 and clang++ 3.5.

Comment: Yes, I think that's pretty much the fix to this specific problem, but I'm not sure if the use of move semantics here is appropriate (as I said). Consider `apply` or any other function that takes a function `F` and applies it to the elements of a list: `F` is called multiple times; if `F` is the result of `curry`, you might end up moving from the same objects several times.

Comment: @dyp Right. It also works if I simply gives `first` to `func` without any `move`. That may prevent the problem.

Comment: Interesting question. I tried another approach using variadic polymorphic functors (can be polymorphic lambda in C++14) and it simplifies implementation a bit as you don't have to care about argument types and indices. Also it supports currying and composition of polymorphic functors/lambdas as well.

Comment: @apoorvkul Yes. I intended to simplify that madness after the standardization of C++14 was approved :)

Comment: For what it's worth, I got 123523348 with clang-3.5 compiling in c++11 mode, 200753444 with c++14. Looks to me like a fun bug.

Comment: Well, actually it's not that helpful at all.  I get different answers every time I run it. Non-deterministic programs with no input and no random calls. Nice..

Comment: @vmrob If that doesn't tell you that you're using dangling pointers/references, I don't know what else would. I think this question is just an obfuscation of very basic snafus. The whole currying thing is just a good pretense :)

Comment: What you are doing is _not_ called 'currying'. It's called 'partial application' and can already be done with `std::bind`. _Currying_ would allow your `add` lambda to be called like `add(5)(10)`, i.e. make it take one argument and return a new callable.

Comment: @Xeo Note that, as Joachim mentioned, using std::bind doesn't work when the resulting function needs to be used with his compose function. This is due to limitations in template deduction.

Comment: @vmrob: No, this is due to a limitation in the `compose` function presented here, as it (wrongfully) inspects the input's argument / result types and uses `std::function`. :) To Morwenn: Note how the implementation of `std.functional` (linked to in the documentation) has changed the `curry` function to `partial`, with a deprecated version of `curry` for backwards compatibility.

Comment: @Xeo My apologies, I'm not at all familiar with the D language.

Comment: @Xeo Good catch. That's kind of fun.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I believe others have mentioned in your comments, the issues relating to your code are lifetime issues. Note that you're passing the second parameter, `5`, to `curry` as an rvalue:

```
auto add5 = curry(add, 5);
```

Then, in the invocation of the `curry` function, you're creating a copy of that variable on the stack as one of the parameters:

```
auto curry(Function&& func, First first)
```

Then, in your call to `curry_impl` you pass a reference to the `first` that won't exist once your call to `curry` completes. As the lambda you're producing uses a reference to a variable that no longer exists, you get undefined behavior.

To fix the problem you're experiencing, simply change the prototype of `curry` to use a universal reference to `first` and make sure you don't pass rvalues to `curry`:

```
template<typename Function, typename First,
         typename Indices=indices_range<1, function_traits<Function>::arity>>
auto curry(Function&& func, First&& first)
    -> decltype(curry_impl(std::forward<Function>(func), std::forward<First>(first), Indices()))
{
    using FirstArg = typename function_traits<Function>::template argument_type<0>;
    static_assert(std::is_convertible<First, FirstArg>::value,
                  "the value to be tied should be convertible to the type of the function's first parameter");
    return curry_impl(std::forward<Function>(func), std::forward<First>(first), Indices());
}
```

Then in main:

```
int foo = 5;
auto add5 = curry(add, foo);
```

Of course, limiting yourself to lvalue expressions is a pretty huge problem with the interface, so it's worth mentioning that if you planned on utilizing this outside of an exercise, it would be a good idea to provide an interface where rvalues can be used.

Then again, I would change it so that the resulting functor owns copies of its components as `std::bind` does. I know I would be a little perplexed if the following code didn't work:

```
std::function<int(int)> foo()
{
    std::function<int(int, int)> add = [](int a, int b)
    {
        return a + b;
    };
    return curry(add, 5);
}
```

---

Edit: I see now that some versions of gcc still require the values to be captured by value into the resulting lamba. GCC 4.9.0 20131229 is the build I tested it on which works fine.

Edit #2: specified correct usage per [Xeo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/500104/xeo)

Comment: Changing the parameter to a universal reference doesn't fix the lifetime bug. The passed argument (the `5` in your `foo`) only lives until the end of the `return` expression, and is _still_ captured by reference in the resulting lambda. This 'fixed' code _only_ works if you pass an lvalue that lives longer than the resulting lambda.

Comment: @Xeo I don't know what I was thinking about the 5 literal being an lvalue. Editted to reflect that. I'll bet this appears to fix the problem only because it's a constant. The correct code would have to change to initialize another variable to 5, then pass that to curry. Not a good usage at all.

Comment: Good, I see where I got confused. Also, I got confused the cases when references collapsing happens and when it does not. No wonder it does not work in the end...

Comment: I agree you should use copy-by-default as in the Standard Library functional parts. Then, you can opt-in to reference semantics by using something like `std::ref`/`std::cref`. IMO, this leads to less error prone code, since you can only get the lifetime issues if you explicitly use `std::ref` etc.