# C++ lambda function access write violation

Tags: c++, c++11, lambda

I'm learning how to use C++ lambda functions along with `<functional>`'s `function` class. I am trying to solve this [Code Golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/16707/9-hole-challenge?rq=1) as practice (challenge is Curry for Dinner)

I have this function:

```
// This creates a function that runs y a number of 
// times equal to x's return value.
function<void()> Curry(function<int()> x, function<void()> y)
{
    return [&]() {
        for (int i = 0; i < x(); i++)
        {
            y();
        }
    };
}
```

To test this I have this code in my main():

```
auto x = [](){ return 8; };
auto y = [](){ cout << "test "; };
auto g = Curry(x, y);
```

This throws `Access violation reading location 0xCCCCCCCC.` in Functional.h.

Yet when I copy-paste the lambda function from inside Curry() to inside my main like this:

```
auto x = [](){ return 8; };
auto y = [](){ cout << "test "; };
auto g = [&]() {
    for (int i = 0; i < x(); i++)
    {
        y();
    }
};
```

I get the code running as expected. Why does this happen?

Comment: I'm too lazy to answer the others, but [here's Curry for Dinner in C++14](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/7d46f072f30d2c5d "Live at Coliru"): `auto Curry=[](auto x,auto y){return[=]{for(auto i=x();i--;y());};};`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You have a few problems.

Here:

```
  return [&]() {
```

you capture **by reference**.  Any variables you capture has to have a lifetime that exceeds your own.  It means that running the lambda becomes undefined behavior after the variables you capture&use lifetime ends.  As you are returning this lambda, and capturing local state, this seems likely to happen.  (Note I said variables -- due to a quirk in the standard, `[&]` captures variables not the data referred to by variables, so even capturing `&` function arguments by `[&]` is not safe.  This may change in future revisions of the standard...  There are neat optimizations that this particular set of rules allow in lambda implementations (reduce `[&]` lambdas to having 1 pointer worth of state(!)), but it also introduces the only case in C++ where you have a reference to a reference variable in effect...)

Change it to

```
  return [=]() {
```

and capture by-value.

Or even:

```
  return [x,y]() {
```

to list your captures explicitly.

When using a lambda which does not outlive the current scope, I use `[&]`.  Otherwise, I capture by value explicitly the stuff I am going to use, as lifetime is important in that case.

Next:

```
    for (int i = 0; i < x(); i++)
```

you run `x` once for every loop iteration.  Seems silly!

Instead:

```
    auto max = x();
    for (auto i = max; i > 0; --i)
```

which runs `max` times, and as it happens works if the return value of `x` was changed to `unsigned int` or whatever.

Or:

```
    int max = x();
    for (int i = 0; i < max; ++i)
```

which both runs `x` once, and behaves better if `x` returns `-1`.

Alternatively you can use the obscure operator `-->`:

```
    int count = x();
    while( count --> 0 )
```

if you want to make your code unreadable.  ;)

Comment: Even changing the parameters to references (because the objects do live long enough) may not help.  Further detail at http://stackoverflow.com/q/21443023/103167

Comment: @BenVoigt yep, the lifetime of the reference does not exceed the scope.  The lifetime of the referenced data does.  I guess I should be clear that it is variables, not data, I am talking about.

Comment: @Yakk: I don't think it's a quirk or subject to change; it allows a very sensible scheme where lambda capture-by-reference is implemented by storing a copy of the stack pointer.  All discussed in that linked question.

Comment: @BenVoigt yep, I get it.  I can still call it a quirk, even if it opens up optimization opportunities.

Comment: Why not `for (auto i = x(); i > 0; --i)` ? Extra verbosity doesn't seem to be necessary

Comment: @icepack first, that is no shorter than my `-->` version ;) (after renaming `count`).  Second, I find storing the `max` of a loop or iteration worthwhile for debugging, and in release builds its existence gets optimized away anyhow.