# How tu use a C++11 lambda asynchronously when capturing by reference

Tags: c++11, asynchronous, lambda, capture

Can somebody explain the behavior of the following code?

When I explicitely convert my lambda to an `std::function`, the lambda correctly captures my variable `n`.

When it is implicitly converted to an `std::function` (using a temporary), then the capture fails.

I am using `g++-4.9 (Ubuntu 4.9-20140406-1ubuntu1) 4.9.0 20140405 (experimental) [trunk revision 209157]`

```
#include <chrono>
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <thread>

std::shared_ptr<std::thread> call(const std::function<void()>& functor)
{
    // Execute our functor asynchronously
    return std::make_shared<std::thread>([&functor]
    {
        // Make sure all temporary are deallocated
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(1));
        // Execute our functor
        functor();
    });
}

int main()
{
    int n{};
    std::cout << "in main   " << &n << std::endl;
    // -> in main   0x7fffd4e1a96c

    auto lambda = [&n]
    {
        std::cout << "in lambda " << &n << std::endl;
    };

    // Here we do an explicit convertion to std::function
    std::cout << "explicit convertion" << std::endl;
    auto function = std::function<void()>{ lambda };
    auto pThreadFunction = call(function);
    pThreadFunction->join();
    // -> in lambda 0x7fffd4e1a96c

    // Here we use an implicit convertion to std::function
    std::cout << "implicit convertion" << std::endl;
    auto pThreadLambda = call(lambda);
    pThreadLambda->join();
    // -> in lambda 0

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: How does _the capture fails_ manifest itself?

Comment: As mentioned in the comments in the code, the address of the captured variable is `0`.

Comment: Related? http://stackoverflow.com/q/21443023 This should imply the first one is also UB.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The lifetime of a temporary constructed for binding to a `const` reference function parameter is the full-expression containing that function call, so your thread function is referring to a dangling reference.

You should only capture variables into a thread function by reference if you can guarantee that the lifetime of the variable contains the lifetime of the thread, as you have done in the case where `function` is a local variable in `main`.

One alternative would be to call `join` within the full-expression that constructs the temporary:

```
call(lambda)->join();
```

Another more general solution would be to capture `functor` by value in your thread function.

Comment: I agree that the `std::function` will only live for the call to `call` but the lambda it refers to is still valid until `join` is done

Comment: @VincentRobert the `std::function` is destructed, so it doesn't refer to anything.

Comment: You might want to clarify that the capture that's causing the problem is the one in `call` (since it's capturing the parameter by reference), not anything in `main`

Comment: Thanks, you helped clarify my thought and I finally understood my problem. Thanks