# Is it safe to capture a member reference if the class storing the original reference goes out of scope?

Tags: c++, c++11, lambda

Consider this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>

std::function<void()> task;
int x = 42;

struct Foo
{
   int& x;

   void bar()
   {
      task = [=]() { std::cout << x << '\n'; };
   }
};

int main()
{
   {
      Foo f{x};
      f.bar();
   }

   task();
}
```

My instinct was that, as the actual referent still exists when the task is executed, we get a newly-bound reference at the time the lambda is encountered and everything is fine.

However, on my GCC 4.8.5 (CentOS 7), I'm seeing some behaviour (in a more complex program) that suggests this is instead UB because `f`, and the reference `f.x` itself, have died. Is that right?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. In task you bind to `int& x` which is no longer valid when `Foo` is destroyed.

Comment: I suppose a "literal" reading of the program says I'm capturing a `this` that'll go out of scope and that `x` inside the task is just short for a now-invalid `this->x`.

Comment: @freakish: But do I? Am I not binding a new variable to `::x`? What is `r2` bound to in `int x = 42; int& r1 = x; int& r2 = r1;`?

Comment: That nasty implicit capture of `x` in the fact of the explicit `=` is a real PITA.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I'm not really sure how it works formally and how to deduce this from the standard. I guess it was my intuitive observation. :)

Comment: If true, it's not even that easy to fix either :(

Comment: Actually, this could be a dupe of https://stackoverflow.com/q/21443023/560648.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: Not sure I like that duplicate. In your case `::x` is valid for the lifetime of the program. Being able to answer, unfortunately, is above my pay grade.

Comment: @Bathsheba: I believe that my `::x` is equivalent to Magnus's `main()::i`, which also seemingly lives as long as it is needed. The examples do differ, however, in that I'm capturing `this` instead.

Comment: @Bathsheba: We get paid? ;)

Comment: A lot has changed since you lowered your profile ;)

Comment: @StoryTeller: Figures!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

To capture a member reference you need to utilize the following syntax (introduced in C++14):

```
struct Foo
{
   int & m_x;

   void bar()
   {
      task = [&l_x = this->m_x]() { std::cout << l_x << '\n'; };
   }
};
```

this way `l_x` is an `int &` stored in closure and referring to the same `int` value `m_x` was referring and is not affected by the `Foo` going out of scope.

In C++11 we can workaround this feature being missing by value-capturing a pointer instead:

```
struct Foo
{
   int & m_x;

   void bar()
   {
      int * p_x = &m_x;
      task = [=]() { std::cout << *p_x << '\n'; };
   }
};
```

Comment: Agreed. Only available since C++14 though right? Think I'm going to have to declare a pointer somewhere and take that by value.

Comment: Though my question is about C++11, this is close enough as it confirms the problem and suggests a solution I'd like to use in the future - and converting to a C++11 solution is now trivial (and works, btw).

Answer (score 3):

You can capture a reference member in C++11 by creating a local copy of the reference and explicit capture to avoid capturing `this`:

```
void bar()
{
    decltype(x) rx = x; // Preserve reference-ness of x.
    static_assert(std::is_reference<decltype(rx)>::value, "rx must be a reference.");
    task = [&rx]() { std::cout << rx << ' ' << &rx << '\n'; }; // Only capture rx by reference.
}
```

Comment: And this doesn't suffer from the same problem purely because we've eliminated the `this` intermediary?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Yes, because it uses explicit capture `this` is not captured. And if the member is not a reference it breaks at compile time.

Comment: I get that `this` doesn't come into your example - I'm trying to arrive at unquestionable proof that this one change results in a wholly valid program

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit All these references end up referring the global `x`, since initializing a reference with a reference does not make a reference to a reference, if I understand you correctly.

Comment: Right, which is what I thought my original solution would do, but it didn't, hence my caution - I guess I was hoping you'd flesh it out a bit with a proof to that end